# Find an example of a non-empty subset

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of a non-empty subset U of $R^2$ simultaneously satisfying the two properties that U is closed under vector addiction, and whenever **u** $\in$ U then (-1)**u** $\in$ U as well, but which is not a subspace of $R^2$

Comment: Points with rational coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Always remember not to omit the underlying number field when you mention a linear space. Is it on $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$ or any other field? But anyway $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ must be an example since the field shall be a supset of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\frac{1}{2}\times(1,1)\notin \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)